# likert stacked bar chart

Tags: r, stacked-chart

I'm new to R.  I have looked at several websites about how to make a Likert stacked bar chart in R (and a question on this website too).  I don't understand any of them.  Every example has numerous, NUMEROUS commands.  It's like as if they're showing me how to plot by including every possible attribute they can think of, and all I want is an answer: plot(x,y)

For simplicity, lets say my data has 2 questions, on a 3pt Likert scale (A, B, and C), arranged in a CSV like this:

```
        A    B    C
  Q1   25   31   56
  Q2   73   19    4
```

The numbers represent the number of people who answered the question with that response. For example, for question #2, 19 people chose Likert response B.

What is the shortest number of commands that can create a stacked bar chart from that?

Comment: A stacked bar chart is easy enough: `barplot(t(mydata))` - but you probably need to show an example of the output that you would like. And you should understand that such output might require numerous commands _i.e._ there is not a basic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of the steps:

```
Question <- c("Q1", "Q2")
A <- c(25,73)
B <- c(31,19)
C <- c(56,4)


data <- data.frame(Question, A, B, C)


# Install the "reshape" package
install.packages("reshape")

# Load reshape package into working directory

library(reshape)

# Melt data to long format

data.melt <- melt(data, id = ("Question"), measure.vars = c("A", "B", "C"))

# Install ggplot2 package

install.packages("ggplot2")

# Load ggplot2 package into working directory

library(ggplot2)

# Create your figure

ggplot(data.melt, aes(x = Question, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: No, I still have a lot to learn before I understand this, but this is the most concise example I've seen so far, thank you!  Is it easy to modify this code to make it a diverging stacked bar chart?

Comment: @J.P. - you should take a look at the `likert` package for R.

Comment: Yea, shouldn't be to troublesome to make this into a diverging stacked bar plot. Just need to decide how you want it to look and then you can spice it up from there.

Comment: @thelatemail, I will, thank you. However, my problem is that R documentation is Greek to me (and I don't speak Greek).  Mathematica documentation, on the other hand, is crystal clear to me.