# Likert stacked bar chart in ggplot with pre and posttest

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I am brand new to R and a teacher, so thank you for your patience. I've searched many other questions on Likert stacked bar charts ([this one is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196827/likert-stacked-bar-chart), but not exactly what I am struggling with). I can't seem to find one that discusses how to pull the results of both survey pre- and post-test into the same stacked bar chart. I've read through Hayley's R for Data Science book, examples on GitHub, the R Companion Handbook, and the R Cookbook. Still really need some help, as a beginner.

I have a set of 12 student questions, each with a pre- and post-test response, on a scale of Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree.

My question is: How did the student survey responses change before and after a test?

My data originally was displayed as:

```
Student sex(F=0,M=1)  PreTestQ1   PostTestQ1
1       0              Agree      Disagree
2       0              Disagree   Agree
3       1              Agree      Agree
4       1              Disagree   Agree
```

First, I converted the Agrees/Disagrees to numerical data (Strongly Agree = 1, Strongly Disagree = 4, no Neutral option) and tidied the data from wide to long using:

```
    # Set data frame as wide
msse_wide <- read_xls("ProcessDataMSSE.xls")
colnames(msse_wide) # Displays names of columns
head(msse_wide)


# Set data frame as long, after running wide code above
msse_long <- msse_wide %>%
  gather(question,obs_prepost, c(2:25)) # This pulls the columns from 2 to 25 (not including the "sex" column), test it out first as a precaution

# NOW MY DATA IS TIDY!!!! :)
```

And I got:

```
    > msse_long
# A tibble: 1,824 x 3
     sex question obs_prepost
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
 1     0 1Pre               3
 2     0 1Pre               3
 3     0 1Pre               2
 4     0 1Pre               3
 5     0 1Pre               2
 6     0 1Pre               3
 7     0 1Pre               3
 8     0 1Pre               2
 9     0 1Pre               2
10     0 1Pre               4
# … with 1,814 more rows
```

Now I would like to visualize the percentages of Strongly Agree --- Strongly Disagree responses as a stacked bar chart, using percentage responses, AND comparing pre- and post-test as stacked bars one on top of the other (so, with 12 questions pre- and post-, I will have 24 total stacked bar charts).

The ultimate goal is similar to this example from R Companion:
[Simple Stacked Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8824.png) ...except I am stuck on how to pull percentages out of my data, and compare pre- and post-tests one on top of the other.

Comment: that plot that you shared is very hard to read... the x-axis doesn't seem to have much to do with the percentages in each of the bars? Can you add the `dput(msse_long)` output to your question? and show any plotting code you have tried?

Comment: I would prefer having an x-axis that runs from 0% to 100%, but the basic form of the plot is what I am looking for. I am new to R so I do not know how to do plotting code yet.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

[image]

Data:

```
msse_wide <- read.table(text='Student sex(F=0,M=1)  PreTestQ1   PostTestQ1
                              1       0              Agree      Disagree
                              2       0              Disagree   Agree
                              3       1              Agree      Agree
                              4       1              Disagree   Agree',
                        header=TRUE,
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Suggested solution using `dplyr`, `tidyr` `ggplot2` and `scales`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
msse_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Student, sex.F.0.M.1.),
               names_to = "Test") %>% 
  group_by(Test, value) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  mutate(Pct = N / sum(N)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Test, Pct, fill = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

## Edit:

Thanks to a comment from @dc37:

Adding

```
+ coord_flip()
```

to the above code gives:

[image]

Explanation:

Starting from the data in *wide* form we use `pivot_longer` , `tidyr`s successor of `gather` to get the desired structure.

Then we group by `Test` and `value` (the individual answer levels)  and summarize by counting the cases in each group using dplyr's `n` function.

We then mutate (in this case, create) a column where we divide the count for each `Test` - `value` combination by the sum for each `Test` group (`dplyr` 
 now only grouping by the first group, `Test`)

Finally we use `ggplot2` to plot the data and `scales` to label the percent axis.

Comment: Thank you! This gets me closer to my goal, I wasn't aware of the pivot_longer function.

Answer (score -1):

I've got something that seems to work, only the pre- and post-treatments are out of order. This is in base R. Thanks for your help!

```
if(!require(psych)){install.packages("psych")}
if(!require(likert)){install.packages("likert")}
library(readxl)
setwd("MSSE 507 Capstone Data Analysis/")
read_xls("ProcessDataMSSE.xls")


Data = read_xls("ProcessDataMSSE.xls")

str(Data) # tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame classes

### Change Likert scores to factor and specify levels; factors because numeric values are ordinal

Data <- Data[, c(3:26)] # Get rid of the other columns! (Drop multiple columns) 

Data$`1Pre` <- factor(Data$`1Pre`,
                   levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                   ordered = TRUE)

Data$`1Post` = factor(Data$`1Post`,
                     levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                     ordered = TRUE)

Data$`2Pre` <- factor(Data$`2Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`2Post` = factor(Data$`2Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`3Pre` <- factor(Data$`3Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`3Post` = factor(Data$`3Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`4Pre` <- factor(Data$`4Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`4Post` = factor(Data$`4Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`5Pre` <- factor(Data$`5Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`5Post` = factor(Data$`5Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`6Pre` <- factor(Data$`6Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`6Post` = factor(Data$`6Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`7Pre` <- factor(Data$`7Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`7Post` = factor(Data$`7Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`8Pre` <- factor(Data$`8Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`8Post` = factor(Data$`8Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`9Pre` <- factor(Data$`9Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`9Post` = factor(Data$`9Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`10Pre` <- factor(Data$`10Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`10Post` = factor(Data$`10Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`11Pre` <- factor(Data$`11Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`11Post` = factor(Data$`11Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`12Pre` <- factor(Data$`12Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`12Post` = factor(Data$`12Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data <- factor(Data,levels=Data[3:26])
Data
### Double check the data frame

library(psych) # Loads psych package

headTail(Data) # Displays last few and first few data

str(Data) # Shows structure of an object (observations and variables, etc.) - in this case, ordinal factors with 4 levels (1 through 4)

summary(Data) # Summary of the number of times you see a data point

Data$`1Pre` # This allows us to check how many data points are really there

str(Data)
### Remove unnecessary objects, removing the data frame in this case (we've converted that data frame into a table with the read.table function above)

library(likert)

Data <- as.data.frame(Data) # Makes the tibble a data frame

likert(Data) # This will give the percentage responses for each level and group

Result = likert(Data)

summary(Result) # This will give the mean and SD 


plot(Result,
     main = "Pre and Post Treatment Percentage Responses",
     ylab="Questions",
     type="bar")
```